# bash prompt has become vim? How to reset?

Tags: vim

I installed dotfiles from a guy on GitHub (https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles).  I didn't like some of the customizations, so I tried uninstalling it by running

```
./install.sh restore
```

However... my bash command prompt seems to have turned into vim (or at least vim commands work now and I seem to have insert and command modes).  How do I get my normal bash command line back?  (I miss being able to do Ctrl+arrow to jump through words).

Probably a totally n00b question, but I'm just a young vim grasshopper at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: Read the post correctly

edit .bashrc and replace `set -o vi` on line 169 with `set -o emacs`.  If this does not exist (due to the `resotre` command you issued) you can either log out and back in or type `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks Jan!  To get the Ctrl+arrow stuff working, I also had to replace the .inputrc file:

    cp /etc/inputrc ~/.inputrc

As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029118/bash-ctrl-to-move-cursor-between-words-strings